# Change number format of confusion matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, confusion-matrix

I have the following confusion matrix: 
[image]

I would like to change the format of the numbers that, when they exceed the value 99, appear in scientific format. 
I would like them to appear in a standard format. That is: 3.3e + 02 would be 330.

This is the function I have implemented:

```
  cm= confusion_matrix(y_test,predicted_classes)
  plt.figure(figsize=fig_size)
  plt.title('Confusion matrix of the classifier')
  sns.heatmap(cm,annot=True)
  plt.xlabel('Predicted')
  plt.xticks(rotation=45)
  plt.ylabel('True')
  plt.ioff()
  plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `fmt = ".1f"` parameter in `sns.heatmap()`.

You can rewrite your code as follows to get all numbers in scientific format.

```
sns.heatmap(cm,annot=True, fmt=".1f")
```

Refer [this](http://alanpryorjr.com/visualizations/seaborn/heatmap/heatmap/) link for additional customization.